# Heroku Django, Multiple Web Dynos

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

Initially my procfile was looking like
    web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi

Then I added django channels in my app, for this I had to add
    web: daphne ProjectName.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
    worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
in my procfile
Now my procfile looks like

```
web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi
web2: daphne ProjectName.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the procfile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but maybe it will help someone. Change Procfile to:

`web: daphne ProjectName.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2`