# Setup HTTP web through WSGI and Websocket through ASGI on the same Heroku app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, django-channels

I've got a quick question for Heroku Pros. How do you handle both websockets(django-channels) and http web dynos together in a Django app? Here's my Procfile setup-web:

```
gunicorn my_proj.wsgi
worker: celery -A my_proj.celery_app worker 
websocket: daphne my_proj.asgi:application --port 8001 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

I'm using Gunicorn for regular web stuff and Celery for background tasks, which are all good. But the websocket part isn't kicking in at all. This works fine on local (tested on postman) but after deploying on heroku I try to call this endpoint I get to see NO logs `heroku logs -t -d websocket`

I'm using Django-channels with ASGI, hence Daphne (also tried uvicorn), but it just stalls out. After digging around a bit, I stumbled on the fact that Heroku doesn't play nice with multiple ports. Not sure if I've got that right, but assuming I do, how can I get this working? I could do below as well (which is working fine!)

```
web: daphne logistics_service.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: celery -A logistics_service.celery_app worker
```

But I'd rather not switch everything over to ASGI for the basic web stuff.

I have two approaches in mind:

- Do I need to use a process manager like Supervisor?
- Or Maybe create a separate app just for WebSockets in the same pipeline?

How do you guys manage this on Heroku? Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is how the files look like -

**asgi.py**

```
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # "http": django_asgi_app, 
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path(r"chat/<str:room_name>/", WSConsumer.as_asgi()), 
    ]) 
})
```

And, here **WSConsumer** class is an extension of **AsyncWebsocketConsumer**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class WSConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
   ...
```

Also, you'll notice we have only consumer. there is no worker/server.
That because that would be taken care of programmatically(in the view) and not need to expose an endpoint. use case is the system would send WebSocket notification to the application user and they'd just consume it. e.g.

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

def send_ws_notification(room_name, **kwargs):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(room_name, {"type": "notification", "data": kwargs})
```

tried with everything(simple http+websocket) on asgi which works fine but as I mentioned, I don't want to use asgi for simple http endpoints.

I tried with Gunicorn as well(assuming Daphne is not very well supported on Heroku but no luck.

Already visited the below threads, but no answer there as well.

[Django now working channels with ASGI + WSGI in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385774/django-now-working-channels-with-asgi-wsgi-in-heroku?rq=2#comment99482781_56427379)

[Heroku Django, Multiple Web Dynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247093/heroku-django-multiple-web-dynos?rq=2)